# How to change delegate expression to lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I was reading some code and saw the following:

```
Method.Find(delegate(Department depts) { 
     return depts.Id == _departmentId; });
```

The `T Find` method has the following description:

```
public T Find(Predicate<T> match);
// Summary:
//     Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified
//     predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire 
//     System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.
//
// Parameters:
//   match:
//     The System.Predicate<T> delegate that defines the conditions of the element
//     to search for.
// (...)
```

Is it possible to rewrite this method to take a lambda expression as a parameter, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method can *already* accept a lambda expression as a parameter, if you want to pass one to it.

The method simply indicates that it accepts a delegate.  There are several ways of defining a delegate:

1. A lambda (`Find(a => true)`)
2. An anonymous delegate (what you used in your example)
3. A method group `Find(someNamedMethod)`
4. Reflection (`Find((Predicate<Whatever>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(SomeClass), someMethodInfo))`)

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-write the method, you can use a lambda already, as below:

```
Method.Find(x => x.Id == _departmentId );
```

The code you provide is an anonymous delegate

```
Method.Find(delegate(Department depts) { 
 return depts.Id == _departmentId; });
```

a lambda is an anonymous function.